# What is the name of sci-fi movie about miniature aliens battling in space and fragment of one ship enters person's body giving them super powers?

Tags: story-identification, movie

Trying to remember the name of Sci Fi movie about a man who gains super abilities when the fragment of a miniature space craft accidentally enters his finger. Live action American film.

Comment: Can you give us any more info? Animation or live action? When did you see it? Language? Any other plot points?

Answer (score 3):

You're probably misremembering the movie *Deep Red*.  The summary from iMDB:

> After a young girl is accidently infected with an alien substance known as "Deep Red", the astonishing results attract the attention of the illustrious scientist Dr. Newmeyer. Disillusioned security expert Joe Keyes must team up with his estranged wife to protect the girl and her mother from the obsessed scientist who will stop at nothing to get what he wants.

The movie begins with a space battle followed by pieces of a ship plummeting to Earth, where a tiny piece lodges in a little girl's hand, melts and disappears leaving no wound.

Comment: [Seems unlikely](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073582/).