# Falling star movie scene

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching a live action movie back in 2005-2009 where there is a scene in which a guy looks at the sky through a window at night and sees a star falling towards him. The star falls from the sky to his hand. He holds it in his hands and looks at it. The star looked like a Tamarind seed and then it starts to penetrate through his hand while hurting him.

I only remember this scene of the movie.

Comment: This question is very terse and would be greatly improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: There's a scene in Howl's Moving Castle that matches this description; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W_nEyuWJWxM&feature=youtu.be&t=119

Comment: It is a movie. Thanks

Comment: Presumably you mean a ***live action*** movie. That's worth adding into the question because animated movies are also movies.

Comment: Sounds like this guy: https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/space/5511619/14-year-old-hit-by-30000-mph-space-meteorite.html

Comment: Can you clarify the science fiction/fantasy aspects of the film? A falling star striking someone is extremely unusual (two known cases in modern times), but is possible. Were there aliens involved? Magic? Futuristic society?

Comment: Also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/107825/ .

Comment: It is a Sci fi movie. The camera and the way of filming looked like *Heroes* tv series

Comment: This resrmbles aspects of 1984's _[Starman](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088172/)_ starring Jeff Bridges.

Answer (score 4):

If it is animated, I would say Howl's moving castle. Howl is a 9 -10 year old kid that sees stars falling.  He grabs one of the stars and the star tells him something. He either eats it or puts it close to his chest and the star gets his heart.

Comment: Please add details as to how this matches.

Comment: The OP appears to be looking for a live action movie.